# Redux not working with Office JS excel addin

Tags: redux, office-js, redux-toolkit, office-addins, excel-addins

I created an Excel add-in by using Office JS API. But when I try to **implement** **Redux (like Provider,useDispatch,useSelector)** in my project Excel addin throws an **error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of its loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.**

Redux structure is working with the version Office 365 but not working with Excel 2019 and 2016.
My index file is as below, **when I add `<Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>` it breaks.**

```js
    import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
    import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2";
    import { ThemeProvider } from "@fluentui/react";
    import * as React from "react";
    import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import App from "./components/App";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import store from "./store";
    import './taskpane.css'
    
    
    /* global Excel, Office */
    
    initializeIcons();
    
    let isOfficeInitialized = false;
    
    const title = "Contoso Task Pane Add-in";
    
    // This code defines a function called render that takes a Component as an argument.
    // It uses ReactDOM to render the Component inside several other components, including Provider, AppContainer, and ThemeProvider.
    const render = (Component) => {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
            </Provider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById("container")
      );
    };
    
    /* Render application after Office initializes */
    Office.onReady(() => {
      isOfficeInitialized = true;
      render(App);
    });
    
    if ((module as any).hot) {
      (module as any).hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
        const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
        render(NextApp);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Try using `Office.intialize` in place of `Office.onReady`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in#initialize-with-officeinitialize